# Is it Compulsory for FlatList that json response should start with [] always?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I was using flatlist to display data and in response I am getting some data.

But, the json response string is starting with the {}braces and not with the []brackets.

So, was Getting below error :

**Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index Nan**.

After doing log what am I getting in my dataSource of FlatList is `[Object Object]`

I have checked json response in postman and its like : **{{[]}}**, in short its not starting with []brackets.

So, am little confused here that Is it compulsory for FlatList to have dataSource or json response starting with []brackets.

If not then What might be the issue there for the error ? and If is it, the How can I convert it in required format ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Doing like this :

```
 .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({ isLoading: false,dataSource: responseJson.screen_details})

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

But, Still Issue exists with **Objects are not valid as a React child.**

Comment: For the final error, it would seem in your `render` method you are placing either your results or another object. Only valid JSX is allowed in the return statement of `render`. This is unlikely to be related to your `FlatList` issue.

Comment: ya i was displaying whole json response in TEXT right before the FlatList, so there was some {}bracket related issue and that's why it was giving edited error that is : "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `FlatList` the `data` property requires an array, as highlighted [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data). Since `FlatList` works by taking a list of items and rendering a seperate row for each, the `data` property needs to be an array.

Once you receive your JSON data, I would recommend only passing the required array to the FlatList, e.g.:

```
<FlatList
    data={myResponse.listOfItems}
    ...
    />
```

Where `myResponse` is your JSON object and `listOfItems` is your array of items.

Also, according to the docs, there is no `dataSource` property, the correct property is simply `data`.

Comment: okay sir, but what is the way that I can access array from my response : it is as : {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Successfully Fetched Records",
    "screen_details": [ {}, {}, {} ] }   and here I want screen_details

Comment: `response.screen_details`

Comment: I would recommend looking into JSON traversing so that you can learn how this is done: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: and where I can put it, i.e. here in code its :  .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

Comment: `this.setState({ data: response.screen_details})` and in the FlatList `data={this.state.data}`. Make sure the initial state of the component has the data set to an empty array e.g. `this.state = { data: [] }`. I would recommend reading the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to get a clearer idea.

Comment: done with it but still it giving me an error. I have edited question and posted issue over there. Will you pls. checkout, i have done as you suggested.